# listeners not working on dont destroy on load objects in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Never used listeners before so I might just be not understanding how the work properly? But what's happening, is I add a listener to a button every time a specific scene is loaded.

Here is a list of events that stop it working:

1. When I first run the game, the listener works as intended, the buttons are created in the script, and the listener is added.
2. I change the scene, not destroying the object with the script containing the listener.
3. When the scene changes back, the script will re-create the buttons, and re-add the listener to the buttons.
4. Using a simple log to check the method the listener should run, the log will no longer show.

Where the listener is added:

```
foreach (Sprite texture in spriteImages) 
{
    //Creates a button
    GameObject button = Instantiate (shopButtonPrefab) as GameObject;

    // gets the buttons image compnent for changing
    Image buttonImage = button.GetComponent<Image> ();
    Image[] images = button.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();

    int newIndex = spriteIndex;
    button.GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.RemoveAllListeners ();
    button.GetComponent<Button> ().onClick.AddListener (() => ChangePlayerSkin (newIndex));
    spriteIndex++;
}
```

The method that should be called.

```
private void ChangePlayerSkin(int index)
{   
    selectedSkinIndex = index;
    Debug.Log ("noo");
    if (skinPurchased [index]) 
    {
        currentSkinIndex = index;

        foreach (GameObject button in shopButtons) 
        {   
            button.transform.GetChild (2).gameObject.SetActive (false);
        }

        shopButtons [currentSkinIndex].transform.GetChild (2).gameObject.SetActive (true);      
    }
}

// Stops working after the scene is re-loaded
```

Only trying to show relevant code. The buttons are created in OnSceneLoaded method every time a certain scene is run. Then the listener is added. Why will the listener only work the first time the scene is loaded? And not every time the scene is reloaded. Does the dontdestroyonload mess up the listener?

Since asking the question, I have further looked around at the rest of the program am cannot find the error to be anywhere else. Also can't find anything in the documentation relating to this? Still can't find a fix.

I have now tried to add the listener in a separate scripts in the awake method of the buttons. Still the listener will not work.

Comment: Make sure to not have the 'Collapse' toggle active in the Console Window. If active, on the right there's a counter displaying that log message occurrences!

Comment: @ZzAtomiic Definitely not on, thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: Personally I detest the DontDestroyOnLoad workflow... Where/when is `button` created, and which scene is it added to?

Comment: So, I create the buttons everytime the game returns to the main menu, which it does every other scene (It loads a level, then comes back to the main menu and creates the buttons). But the listeners fail to work when it comes back to the main menu. @Immersive

Comment: Which object(s) are `DontdestroyOnLoad`?

Comment: One object involved. Which is the same object with this script on. And it is the only object using this script. The method is called previously in the start or awake method (can't remember which)! @derHugo

Comment: Did you try adding some `Debug.Log` just to see whether the methods are called at all? something like `Debug.Log("Hey I just ran the foreach loop");`. Previously you had it in a`private void OnSceneLoaded()` is this still the case? where is it called from?

Comment: Tried that, you can still see where the log is in the code above ^ @derHugo

Comment: @Mattattack There is no logging within or next to the loop .. only the target method. Maybe the loop isnt executed correctly?

Comment: @derHugo Oh my bad. I've tried logging everywhere to see whats going on. The fact the buttons are created means the loops is executed. I'm not sure how I can check the listeners are properly added. But the first time it is executed, the listerners work. Assuming they are added the second time, then it becomes a problem with the listener? How can I check they have been added?